# gulp coffee watch never finishes on error

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a task that looks like this:

```
gulp.task 'scripts', () ->
  gulp.src(path.scripts)
  .pipe(coffee({bare: true}).on 'error', gutil.log)
  .pipe(concat 'app.min.js')
  .pipe(size())
  .pipe(gulp.dest 'public/js')
```

and my watch looks like this:

```
gulp.task 'watch', () ->
  gulp.watch path.scripts, ['scripts']
```

The watch works just fine as long as I don't try to compile any errors. If i have an error though, it seems to me the watch is still running but is worthlessly waiting for something.

If there are no errors, I get something like this:

```
[18:02:47] Starting 'scripts'...
[18:02:47] all files 1.05 kB
[18:02:47] Finished 'scripts' after 17 ms
```

but if is an error and I just swallow it:

```
[18:03:33] Starting 'scripts'...
```

it never finishes and the watch no longer works even though the console thinks its running. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to continue execution after error you need to emit 'end' event. Try this:

```
gulp.task 'scripts', () ->
  gulp.src(path.scripts)
  .pipe(
    coffee({bare: true})
    .on 'error', (err) ->
      gutil.log err
      @emit 'end'
  )
  .pipe(concat 'app.min.js')
  .pipe(size())
  .pipe(gulp.dest 'public/js')
```